# Create a log system in symfony2

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I want to create a system of logs in symfony2 and I have a question, so I have in service.yml :

```
services:
  my_logger:
   class: Monolog\Logger
   arguments: [Debug]
   calls:
    - [pushHandler, [@my_log_handler]]

   my_log_handler:
     class: Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler
     arguments: [/home/vagrant/Workspace/symfony/app/logs/test.log, 100]
```

I have a class in Utils/Logs like this :

```
class Logs {
    public static function logInfo($a_log) {
        $sc = new ContainerBuilder();
        $logguer = $sc->get('my_logger');
        $logguer->info($a_log);
    }
}
```

And my controller :

```
$categories = array();
Logs::logInfo(print_r($categories));
```

The question is how to modify Utilis/Logs class to be possible to call logInfo method? Help me please...Thx in advance...It's possible to create this?

Comment: Why not use monolog directly?

Comment: Because I need to write 2 lines everytime : $logguer = $sc->get('my_logger');
    $logguer->info($a_log);

Comment: That's a bad reason. Such a extra class is a very ugly design